# Sets formed from intersections of subsets of $\sigma$-algebras containing a fixed element

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on the following problem. I know how to prove the desired result if you assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is countable (and thus finite. It is actually generally part of the proof that a countable $\sigma$-algebra must be finite); however, I can't seem to crack it just using a general $\sigma$-algebra. Here it is:

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$. Given $x \in X$, define $A_x = \bigcap \{B: B \in \mathcal{M}, x \in B\}$. Prove that for $x, y \in X$, $A_x$ and $A_y$ are either identical or disjoint.

This amounts to assuming that $A_x \cap A_y \not = \emptyset$ and showing that $A_x = A_y$. I've been starting by choosing $z \in A_x \cap A_y$ and trying to show that $A_z = A_x = A_y$, but can't seem to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Forgot to put the $\bigcap$ in the problem at first and just edited--sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

That seems false.. consider in $\Bbb R$ the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then $\{0,1\}$ is measurable, $\{0,1\} \in A_0 \cap A_1$ but $0 \neq 1$.

By the way, the elements of the $A_x$ are sets, so you can't just take $z \in A_x \cap A_y$, unless $z$ is a set for you.